# Is to possible to create a single class from two context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am curious to know that is it possible to merge these two below class into single one class.

First DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<BusinessAccount>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MySQLConnectionString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Sector> Sectors { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Campus> Campuss { get; set; }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Second DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext :DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MySQLConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Sector> Sectors { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Campus> Campuss { get; set; }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO if `IdentityDbContext<BusinessAccount>` derived from `DbContext` the second class can be merged to first one.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit IdentityDbContext from DbContext

```
public class IdentityDbContext<T1>: DbContext
{
   // Implementation goes here
}
```

Inherit `ApplicationDbContext` from `IdentityDbContext<BusinessAccount>`

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<BusinessAccount>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MySQLConnectionString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Sector> Sectors { get; set; }    
    public DbSet<Campus> Campuss { get; set; }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Only `IdentityDbContext` is already inheriting `DbContext` - this is part of Identity framework.